# For each Id2 value, get a row with the lowest Id1, and another row with the highest Id1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns like this:

```
Id1     Id2
------------
5286    1481
5391    1482
5546    1483
5702    1482
5747    1482
5833    1484
5850    1482
5878    1485
6000    1482
6035    1486
6181    1482
6259    1481
6274    1487
6378    1488
6379    1489
6400    1482
6469    1485
6575    1485
6822    1488
6876    1481
6901    1482
6931    1481
6939    1490
7083    1491
7214    1482
7241    1492
7429    1493
7498    1482
7541    1482
7618    1494
7745    1495
7797    1496
7869    1482
```

For each `Id2` value, I would like to get a row with the lowest `Id1`, and another row with the highest `Id1`, e.g for `Id2 = 1482`:

```
1482    5391
1482    7869
```

How can I write my (Transact) SQL query to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Bruno, did you read the guidelines as to how to ask a good question on StackOverflow? check them out at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As a rule, it is expected of you to try and solve the problem yourself and provide what steps did you try as part of the question so that we can provide constructive answers and not just plain code.

Comment: Hello, I haven't tried any queries to achieve this, as I can't figure out how to make it: in one single select statement, in mutiple ones, using an intermnediate table... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db733/3/0

```sql
SELECT [Id2], MIN(Id1) AS [Id1]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [Id2]

UNION ALL

SELECT [Id2], MAX(Id1) AS [Id1]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [Id2]

ORDER BY [Id2], [Id1]
```

By using grouping, you can find the `max` and `min` for each value of `[Id2]`.

Comment: Thx, it worked ! I just replaced UNION ALL by UNION to avoid duplicates in case min(Id1)=max)id1)

Comment: Nice! Yeah, that's possible too if the duplicates aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ID1, ID2, 
        RnFirst = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1),
        RnLast = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY ID1 DESC)
    FROM    
        dbo.YourTableNameHere
)
SELECT 
    ID1, ID2,
    CASE
        WHEN RnFirst = 1 THEN 'Highest'
        WHEN RnLast = 1 THEN 'Lowest'
    END AS Label
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    ID2 = 1482 
    AND (RnFirst = 1 OR CTE.RnLast = 1)
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) creates "partitions" (buckets) by `ID2` and numbers the values inside - once by ascending `ID1` values, once by descending values.

Therefore, the highest and the lowest values are both labeled as row.no 1 - once in the ascending, once in the descending list.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT MIN(Id1) AS MINID1 , MAX(Id1) AS MAXID1 FROM IDSS
)
SELECT D1.Id2 , CTE.MINID1 AS [VALUE] FROM IDSS D1
CROSS JOIN CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT D1.Id2 , CTE.MAXID1 AS [VALUE]  FROM IDSS D1
CROSS JOIN CTE
ORDER BY D1.Id2, [VALUE]
```

****SCRIPT USED TO TEST:****

```
CREATE TABLE IDSS (Id1 INT,     Id2 INT)

INSERT INTO IDSS VALUES
(5286 ,   1481),
(5391  ,  1482),
(5546 ,   1483)

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT MIN(Id1) AS MINID1 , MAX(Id1) AS MAXID1 FROM IDSS
)
SELECT D1.Id2 , CTE.MINID1 AS [VALUE] FROM IDSS D1
CROSS JOIN CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT D1.Id2 , CTE.MAXID1 AS [VALUE]  FROM IDSS D1
CROSS JOIN CTE
ORDER BY D1.Id2, [VALUE]
```

**RESULTS:**

```
+------+-------+
| Id2  | VALUE |
+------+-------+
| 1481 | 5286  |
+------+-------+
| 1481 | 5546  |
+------+-------+
| 1482 | 5286  |
+------+-------+
| 1482 | 5546  |
+------+-------+
| 1483 | 5286  |
+------+-------+
| 1483 | 5546  |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN CTE ON 1=1`? When is 1 ever not equal to one?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `MIN` and `MAX` and "unpivot":

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MIN(ID1) AS MinID1,
           MAX(ID1) AS MaxID1,
           ID2
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY ID2)
SELECT V.ID1,
       C.ID2
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Min',C.MinID1),
                        ('Max',C.MaxID1))V(KPI,ID1);
```